# Can I rename an entire neighbourhood in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

My entire neighbourhood (est. 20k+ citizens) is incorrectly named in Google Maps. The whole neighbourhood's name is incorrectly taken after a single historic point being part of it.

Can I rename it? And if yes, then how to achieve this?

I've tried a number of reports, but you must point a specific road or part of road in order to be able to submit a report. And when I did so, such report was rejected, because I was pointing a small part of a single street, but I was trying to report about entire neighbourhood.

Many places has "Suggest an edit" link/button when getting to place's details view. But, when I display details view about entire neighbourhood I do not see such button.